# Pagedown converting everything between <code><pre> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, markdown, pagedown

I am using Pagedown version of Markdown and I have the script running successfully without any errors. Because I am using Grails I have to do all the conversion on the client(correct me if I am wrong).

To do this conversion I am using following script

```
   var converter = new Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    $.each($('.myclass'),function(key,value){
        console.log($(value).html());
        console.log(converter.makeHtml($(value).html()));
        alert(converter.makeHtml($(value).html()));
        $(value).html(converter.makeHtml($(value).text()))
    });
```

But all my text is being surrounded by `<pre>` and `<code>` tags One of the output of log statement is following

```
**Computers calculate numbers in Binary mode?(u0)**
```

gets converted to following rather then HTML

```
<pre><code> **Computers calculate numbers in Binary mode?(u0)**</code></pre>
```

Comment: Why does your last line use `text()` instead of `html()`?

Comment: Oops! I was just trying different options but none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
var converter = new Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

$.each($('.myclass'),function(key,value){
    p = converter.makeHtml($(value).text());

    $(value).html("");
    $(value).append(p);
});
```

Comment: Nope! paragrap still has "**Computers calculate numbers in Binary mode?(u0)**" without HTML tags applied:(

Comment: Wait, what output are you expecting?

Comment: Well, SO converted my text to HTML but my input is "star star Computers calculate numbers in Binary mode?(u0) start star" and I want the statement surrounded in bold tags

Comment: You added your own bold tags, I want my page down script to get converted to HTML by the converter object

Comment: Nope it didn't, still prints all the stars and otherthings in a pre and code tag

Comment: Can you post your HTML containing "myclass"?

Comment: It worked after I added var p = converter.makeHtml(**$.trim($(value).text())**); It seems space in the beginning of the string was responsible for this behavior

Comment: I know I should ask another question, but may be you can help, do you know how can I bring the "code" button in the WMD tool bar?

Comment: I am not sure, have you tried using four spaces in the input?

Comment: Use this link: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/markdown-the-ins-and-outs/